# I want to add an extra column in my existing hive table so that I can have a current time stamp for that day

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, timestamp, hiveddl

Need to add extra date column in my existing hive table so that it picks up the
current date from the system for that day

```
hive (hivejobs)>
select * from my_current_Table;
OK
name   age
Aditya  2
Aditya  7
```

I want to add a date column here so that i can get the current system date for that day as soon as I add a column. I think the work around would be to do a join of two tables with other table with the current system date.

below is my code and thought process.

```
alter table my_current_Table add columns( todays_date current_date());
```

this gives me an error , I am unable to find the actual way to do it

please help.

expected output

```
hive (hivejobs)> 
select * from my_current_Table;

OK
name   age  todays_date
Aditya  2   2019-02-08 13:21:50
Aditya  7   2019-02-08 13:21:50
```

Comment: Is there some problem just using `now()`?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define calculated column in Hive table.

If you want always query today's date, use `current_timestamp` function in the select:

```
select t.*, 
       date_format(current_timestamp,'yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss') as todays_date 
  from my_current_Table t;
```

If you want to add column and store the date when the record was inserted, add column to the table and reload from itself, for example like this:

```
alter table my_current_Table  add columns(load_date string);

insert overwrite table my_current_Table 
select t.*, 
           date_format(current_timestamp,'yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss') as load_date
      from my_current_Table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps for same,

1. Create a temporary table

> create table my_current_Table_temp(name string, age int);

2. Insert data using a file or existing table into the my_current_Table_temp table:

> name|age
>
> Aditya | 2
>
> Aditya | 7

3. Create a table which will contain your final data:

> create table my_current_Table(name string, age tinyint, todays_date
>   string);

4. Insert data from the temporary table and with that also add the columns with default value as current date and time:

> insert overwrite table my_current_Table select name, age,
>   FROM_UNIXTIME( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm') from
>   my_current_Table_temp;